# How to solve address boundary error when adding to `dict` of Redis?

Tags: c, redis

I want to do some basic put/get tests based on `dict`. But when doing `dictAdd`, error was thrown.

**Code**

```
// dict_test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dict.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // create
    dictType hashDictType;
    dict *d = dictCreate(&hashDictType, NULL);
    printf("Created: %s\n", d == NULL ? "Failed" : "OK");
    // put
    char key[] = "hello";
    char value[] = "world";
    dictAdd(d, key, value);
    return 0;
}
```

**Error message**

'./dict_test' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

**GCC version**

Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)

**Compile command**

```
gcc dict_test.c dict.c zmalloc.c siphash.c  -o dict_test
```

I found the error thrown when executing `dictIsRehashing(d)` which is a macro(`#define dictIsRehashing(d) ((d)->rehashidx != -1)`).

So I've tried print `d->rehashidx` directly. But i still got the same error.

```
printf("%ld \n", d->rehashidx);
printf("%s", ((d)->rehashidx) == -1L ? "False" : "True");
```

The output

```
Created: OK
-1 
fish: './dict_test' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Maybe this is a basic c problem. Any hints will be appreciated.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. I download the source code of Redis :）.
2. Paste the demo code under directory `src`.

Comment: When you get a crash the first thing you should to is to run in a debugger so you can catch the crash as it happens and locate where it happens in your code. Then you can also examine variables and their values to see if there's any obvious problems with them. At the very least, please try to create a [mcve] to show us, including the location of the crash and the values of the involved variables.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've updated. You should download Redis source code  during the process. :)

Comment: You should pass key and value of `sds` type.

Comment: @for_stack The problem is I've not init hashfunction. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution by OP.*

The problem is when using `dict` a hash function is required to be init on your own which I thought it have a default one. By define a hash function, the crash problem solved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include "dict.h"

// a hash function defined
uint64_t dictSdsCaseHash(const void *key) {
    // refer to "siphash.c"
    return dictGenCaseHashFunction((unsigned char*)key, (int) strlen((char*)key));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // create
    dictType hashDictType;
    hashDictType.hashFunction = dictSdsCaseHash;
    dict *d = dictCreate(&hashDictType, NULL);
    printf("Created: %s\n", d == NULL ? "Failed" : "OK");
    // put
    char key[] = "hello";
    char value[] = "world";
    dictAdd(d, key, value);
    // get
    dictEntry *entry = dictFind(d, key);
    printf("Value: %s\n", entry->v);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Created: OK
hello 
Value: world
```